# IdentityServer4: How to include email in access_token without the client explicitly requesting it?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, openid, identityserver4

when the user logs in on the IdentityServer4 via Google, I'd like to access the email (and maybe their google-id) but without having the client request it. So it should be accessible every time, so I can put it in the access_token (because our API needs the user's email address).

I've been injecting into the `IProfileService`, also the `IClaimsService` but I can't find the email there. Would it be possible to hook into the Google-SignIn Callback so I can access the response manually?

Thanks!

Comment: The Id Token returned from a google login contains the email already, without you specifically asking for it ... https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding the claims I needed in `AccountController.ExternalLoginCallback` like this:

```
//Add E-Mail claim even if client didn't ask for it
if (claims.Exists(c => c.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email))) {
    additionalClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(ClaimTypes.Email)).Value));
}
```

then I added the claim to the `access_token` by dependency injecting my `ProfileService` class and adding the claims in the `MyProfileService.GetProfileDataAsync` like this:

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>();

    Claim emailClaim = context.Subject.Claims.Where<Claim>(claim => claim.Type.Equals(JwtClaimTypes.Email)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (emailClaim != null)
    {
        claims.Add(emailClaim);
    }

    context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```